# Unable to set CI/CD from GitHub repo on Azure

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I have Azure subscription, which I use to host website, which has code on GitHub repository.

In order to simplify, I want to set up CI/CD using deployment center in Azure Portal.

There is a option to pick GitHub Actions (which I want), but after clicking it and filling all necessary info, I don't have any way to commit the YML workflow file. If I copy the content and commit myself (not through Portal), there are issues with authentication.

I also see error in the Portal:

> Basic authentication is disabled for your app.

which may be closely related, but I don't know how to resovle that error.

[image]

Hosting details:

| Plan Type | App Service plan |
| --- | --- |
| Name | ASP-intrinsicrg-a16e |
| Operating System | Linux |
| Instance Count | 1 |
| SKU and size | Free (F1) |

As advised, I should follow the error and go to configuration and enable basic auth, but it is already enabled:

[image]

Comment: Click on the error, it redirects you to `Configuration=>General Settings`, Turn on Basic Authentication. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/KVoQXnj.png).

Comment: @PravallikaKV Thanks for the swift answer, tried it, but with no luck

Comment: Refresh and check again.

Comment: @PravallikaKV See my edit - i had it already checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue today. I have solved it by following these steps: Configuration > General Settings > Basic Auth Publishing Credentials Off > Refresh > Basic Auth Publishing Credentials ON > Refresh

Hope it will work for you too :)

Comment: Ridiculous, but works!